# undefined reference to `yylex', msys2/mingw issues

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, msys

I wouldn't exactly say I was new to c++ but I'm completely defeated by this issue. I'm trying to compile a commodore 64 emulator for retroarch: https://github.com/libretro/vice-libretro, on windows using msys2 and mingw32-w64, the 64bit bit version of mingw. I have a linking error...

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./vice/src/monitor/mon_parse.o:mon_parse.c:(.text+0x9ca): undefined reference to `yylex'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./vice/src/monitor/mon_parse.o:mon_parse.c:(.text+0x2bdd): undefined reference to `make_buffer'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./vice/src/monitor/mon_parse.o:mon_parse.c:(.text+0x2c03): undefined reference to `free_buffer'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./vice/src/monitor/mon_parse.o:mon_parse.c:(.rdata$.refptr.last_len[.refptr.last_len]+0x0): undefined reference to `last_len'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./vice/src/monitor/mon_parse.o:mon_parse.c:(.rdata$.refptr.opt_asm[.refptr.opt_asm]+0x0): undefined reference to `opt_asm'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./vice/src/monitor/mon_parse.o:mon_parse.c:(.rdata$.refptr.new_cmd[.refptr.new_cmd]+0x0): undefined reference to `new_cmd'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:397: vice_x64_libretro.dll] Error 1
```

so `undefined reference to 'yylex'` would seem, from my research, to indicate that i'm missing either flex or bison. I've tried to install them both in the msys2 shell using `pacman -S bison flex` and this results in 2 additional files, among others, in my installation folder `C:\msys64\usr\lib`

`libfl.a` and
`liby.a`

I've tried to amend the projects makefile to search this location when compiling by adding the following...

```
LDFLAGS += --shared -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--version-script=$(CORE_DIR)/libretro/link.T -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/usr/lib
LDFLAGS += -lws2_32 -luser32 -lwinmm -ladvapi32 -lshlwapi -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lpsapi -liphlpapi -lshell32 -luserenv -lmingw32 -shared -lgcc -lm -lmingw32 -lfl -ly
```

Note the addition of `-L/usr/lib` and `-lfl -ly`

But when I do this the compiler complains it can't find the libraries
`cannot find -lfl`
`cannot find -ly`

So I searched for other location where libs definately were being loaded from, a search for libgcc.a found it was in `C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib` so I guess the directories are mapped differently somehow.

Okay, so i put the two .a files in that folder and now I'm back the to error shown at the top of the page, specifically `undefined reference to 'yylex'`

How on earch can I possibly fix this, please, I spent the whole day today bashing my head against a monitor, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Compiling a complicated emulator, like that, is already a major challenge that tasks even experienced developers. But to try to do that on a compiler that was crammed into a foreign operating system that it wasn't really designed for (gcc on windows) just adds even more layers of complexity on top of it. Only someone who've done exactly what you're attempting to do might know the right process for this. P.S. `yylex` is not flex, but the output of flex's robo-generated lexical analyzer. Something is not getting built and/or linked, correctly, in your source tree.

Comment: Well you're comment makes me feel less awful about the time i've invested in compiling emulators vs tangible results. I've had some success stories though and I know I can get this one too, so if you have any suggestions I'm all open to trying them.

Comment: You'd have to search through the source tree to find where yylex lives. It's either been generated by flex, or it's not. If it's not, then the next step is to figure out why not. If it's been generated, the next step is to figure out why it's not getting compiled and linked in. You need to understand what flex and bison are, and how they work.

Comment: Well the file in question is `./vice/src/monitor/mon_parse.o:mon_parse.c` but I think the main issue is simply that I don't have mingw setup correctly, since the linker is trying to link to bison (https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Lexical.html#:~:text=4.3%20The%20Lexical%20Analyzer%20Function,to%20as%20a%20lexical%20scanner) and for some reason can't. I'm sure there's a simple solution regarding how my environment is set up. I've read some similar problems which list the issue of not extern-ing it properly to link between c++ and c but the source in question seems to be fine.